# Revert local git codebase post changes

Tags: git, svn

I have a git repo I pulled down. I made some changes to the code locally. I simply want to revert those changes and not use them. Is there any way to do this???? Why is it so difficult? I don't want to have to commit anything... I just want to revert my local code back.

I am looking for a simple command to do this.

For example, SVN made it extremely easy. All I had to do was delete the file and "update my code" and it would be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard HEAD` will reset head and get rid of any changes you've made.

Comment: `HEAD` refers to the tip of your most recent commit. In your case, it points to the state of the repository when you pulled it.

Answer (score 0):

`Git` is not *hard* but just very different from `SVN`. This command will revert all changes to tracked files:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```